# CSS Grids will not align

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
.panel_wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    padding: 2em;
}
.panel_content {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border: solid;
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 2/3;
}
.panel_navigation_left {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    border: solid;
}


.panel_navigation_right {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 3/4;
    border: solid;
}

.navigation {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel_wrapper">
    <div class="panel_content">
        CONTENT
    </div>

    <div class="panel_navigation_left navigation">
        BAC
    </div> 
    <div class="panel_navigation_right navigation">
       FORWARD
    </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xc2kh84v/

I have 3 columns here. I want my outer two columns to be side by side as the middle column, and have the same height. Right now its just forcing it onto another row and I don't understand why.

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
>
> > I think this is enough detail, I will add more if needed.

Comment: You can use the `order` property, but you can also fix it using the `grid-row: 1` property to force them to the first row. My favorite way of defining a layout is using grid-areas though, I think it looks much cleaner https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `grid-row: 1/2;` to all elements. Also remove `display:grid` for grid elements unless you want to create a subgrid. The alignment issues of content comes from the margin bottom.

```css
.panel_wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    padding: 2em;
}
.panel_content {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border: solid;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 1/2;
}
.panel_navigation_left {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    border: solid;
}


.panel_navigation_right {
    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    border: solid;
}

.navigation {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel_wrapper">
    <div class="panel_content">
        CONTENT
    </div>

    <div class="panel_navigation_left navigation">
        BAC
    </div> 
    <div class="panel_navigation_right navigation">
       FORWARD
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it  using `order`:

### DEMO (content is shorter because you set `margin-bottom`)

```css
.panel_wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    padding: 2em;
}
.panel_content {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border: solid;
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    order:2;
}
.panel_navigation_left {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    border: solid;
    order:1;
}


.panel_navigation_right {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 3/4;
    border: solid;
    order:3;
}

.navigation {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel_wrapper">
    <div class="panel_content">
        CONTENT
    </div>

    <div class="panel_navigation_left navigation">
        BAC
    </div> 
    <div class="panel_navigation_right navigation">
       FORWARD
    </div>

</div>
```